# SQL: GROUP BY records and then get last record from each group?

Tags: php, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Only last entry in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438938/sql-server-only-last-entry-in-group-by)

I have a table like this:

```
id| name  | attendence
1 | Naveed| 1
2 | Naveed| 1
3 | Adil  | 1
4 | Adil  | 1
```

I use following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `attendence`=1 GROUP BY name
```

The result with above query:

```
id| name   | attendence
3 | Adil   | 1
1 | Naveed | 1
```

## Question:

Above result group rows by name but show first row from each group. I want to select last row(by id) from each group.

For example:

```
id| name   | attendence
2 | Naveed | 1
4 | Adil   | 1
```

How to write query for above result.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT * FROM test WHERE attendence = 1 GROUP BY name` throw an error??

Comment: @egrunin: Assuming that NAVEED is using MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: http://php.azerot.com/sql-group-by-get-last-record-from-each-group/
here is the same problem for your question's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM test a 
WHERE a.attendence = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from test where name = a.name and id > a.id and attendence = 1)
GROUP BY name
```

Might not even need the group by anymore.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX("id"), "name" FROM "test" WHERE "attendence" = 1 GROUP BY "name"
```

Comment: Why would you use double quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Max(ID) FROM table WHERE attendance = 1 GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `attendence`=1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

That will only select the row that meets the criteria with the highest id.

Comment: It is giving me only one record. Order By is applied after Group By here.

Comment: Yes, it is only giving you one record. That is what the LIMIT 1 is for.  You stated you only wanted the last row.  This will give you only the last row based on the id.  If you still want all the rows returned, take off the phrase `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: You did not understand my question. I want to get all groups but each group should be represented by last row of that group.

Comment: You are correct.  I did misunderstand the question.  `Fosco` appears to have the best answer imo.