# MySQL query to select only last rows of groups of dates

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have the following query:

> SELECT elo, date(date_calculated) date FROM users_historical_elo WHERE uid =36 order by id asc

that produces this result:

`| elo | date`

`|984|2011-04-04`

`|1010|2011-04-04`

`|1036|2011-04-04`

`|1016|2011-04-08`

`|1000|2011-04-08`

`|944|2011-04-09`

`|973|2011-04-09`

`...`

I need help writing a query that selects only the last "elo" grouping by date. So the output should be:

`| elo | date`

`|1036|2011-04-04`

`|1000|2011-04-08`

`|973|2011-04-09`

`...`

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `|1016|2011-04-08`, right?

Comment: Oh sorry, you have an `order by id`, ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449757/sql-group-by-records-and-then-get-last-record-from-each-group

Comment: And is there a field `date_calculated` ?

Comment: @NAVEED, the code I accepted as answer here is more than twice as fast, maybe you should try this one instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `id` is the primary key of the table, then this will do:

```
SELECT elo
     , date(date_calculated) AS date
FROM users_historical_elo 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id
      FROM users_historical_elo
      WHERE uid =36
      GROUP BY date(date_calculated)
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.id = users_historical_elo.id
ORDER BY grp.id ASC
```

Comment: for moral extra credit ;) how could I modify this query if I had the same situation, but I needed to select the *second-to-last* elo grouped by date?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`SELECT elo, date(date_calculated) date FROM users_historical_elo WHERE uid =36 group by date order by id asc`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use MAX and GROUP By. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-max-function.htm

I think this will work

```
SELECT elo, MAX(date(date_calculated)) date 
FROM users_historical_elo 
WHERE uid =36 
GROUP BY elo 
ORDER BY id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 SELECT elo, MAX(date) FROM users_historical_elo
```

Would return the elo and the last date for any elo, which seems to be what you are asking for?