# SQL request to both group responses and retrieve only the last line of each

Tags: mysql

I have a table without IDs. it has 3 columns: the name of a computer, its status (on/off) at the moment of the poll, and the timestamp of the insertion.

if I run

```
select * from computers group by name;
```

I get a line for each computer (there are 200 different ones), but these lines don't always hold the latest entry for it.
I then tried

```
select computers group by name order by timestamp asc;
```

But I get incoherent responses (some recent timestamps, some old ones... no idea why).

It's basically the same problem as here : [SQL: GROUP BY records and then get last record from each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449757/sql-group-by-records-and-then-get-last-record-from-each-group), but I don't have ids to help :(

Comment: have you tried order by name, timestamp asc?

Comment: You have multiple row for each computer and you want the last row added by using timestamp colomn ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger yes, for each computer i want the last row added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT computers.name,
       computers.status,
       computers.timestamp
  FROM ( SELECT name,
                MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
           FROM computers
          GROUP
             BY name
       ) AS t
  JOIN computers
    ON computers.name = t.name
   AND computers.timestamp = t.max_timestamp
;
```

The above uses this subquery to finds the greatest `timestamp` for each `name`:

```
SELECT name
       MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
  FROM computers
 GROUP
    BY name
;
```

and then it gathers fields from `computers` whose `name` and `timestamp` match something that the subquery returned.

The reason that your `order by` clause has no effect is that it comes too "late": it's used to order records that are going to be returned, after it's already determined that they *will* be returned. To quote from [§11.16.3 "`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with Hidden Columns" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) on this subject:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values the server chooses.

Another way is to write a *correlated* subquery, and dispense with the `GROUP BY` entirely. This:

```
SELECT name, status, timestamp
  FROM computers AS c1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM computers
           WHERE name = c1.name
             AND timestamp > c1.timestamp
        )
;
```

finds all rows in `computers` that haven't been superseded by more-recent rows with the same `name`. The same approach can be done with a join:

```
SELECT c1.name, c1.status, c1.timestamp
  FROM computers AS c1
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN computers AS c2
    ON c2.name = c1.name
   AND c2.timestamp > c1.timestamp
 WHERE c2.name IS NULL
;
```

which is less clear IMHO, but may perform better.

Comment: it works EXACTLY like I wanted it, BUT the request took 19 seconds, and my database is only 2 days old. It will quickly become unsustainable, what can I do ?

Comment: @Cystack: I've updated my answer to give some variants that dispense with the `GROUP BY` and may perform better. (The version with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is likely to perform the best, though it's also the least clear IMHO.)

Comment: thank you very much. do you think I would be better off (faster) re writing and porting the table, and using an id for each entry ?

Comment: or maybe having an additionnal table that only retains the last status of each computer ?

Comment: Without knowing more about your data and your needs, it's hard for me to give you categorical advice; but yes, it's likely that you'll want two tables, one with current information (say, `id`, `name`, `current_status`, and `last_modified`) and one with historical information. Google "slowly changing dimension" for information on the different types of approaches that people use to handle these sorts of situations in general.

Comment: Im reading it right now. Your last proposition is giving me a syntax error, and Im not good enough at SQL to detect where it comes from :(

Comment: What is the exact SQL you're running, and what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: MySQL v5.5+, I get a "there is an error near "LEFT OUTER JOIN" etc. until the end of the request

Comment: I just ran `create table computers (name varchar(20), status char(1), timestamp timestamp);` followed by my *exact* query above, and it did not give any syntax error. (It *did* give me the error that "Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous", which I had to address by prefixing each of the field-list columns with `c1.` -- I'll update my answer -- but nothing like what you describe.) Unless you're willing to post the exact query you're using, I think you're on your own for this one, sorry. :-/

Comment: @Cystack: As for speed of query, you should look at the indexes on the table and the query plan that is in use for the first query.  The chances are you don't have any indexes and the system is having to do sequential scans over the table.  This MySQL feature of allowing GROUP BY without listing all non-aggregate columns seems to cause more confusion than benefit.  At least, it triggers quite a lot of questions on SO, but then again, those who get it to work as they want don't need to ask questions about why.

Comment: spot on @JonathanLeffler ;) what should I index? everything?

Comment: @Cystack: A single index on `(name, timestamp)` should help considerably.

Comment: would you mind explaining a bit on why this was the right thing to index ?

Comment: The index on `(name, timestamp)`, which is what I would have suggested had I been paying attention, effectively does the grouping for you by listing all the rows for a given name together in the index, in time order. The optimizer doesn't need to read the data while processing the inner query, and it can rather easily find the maximum timestamp for each name. A 300-times performance improvement is extreme, but proper indexing can often help vastly. Over-indexing slows up both update operations (INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE), and the optimization process (because the optimizer has more options).