# Entity with versioning: optimal way of getting a list of last version using SQL

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

*The question is about SQL on SQL Server 2012.*

### Background:

There is an entity called **Entity**.

**Entity** can have *N* **EntityVersion** (*1:n*).

**EntityVersion** may be approved or not. If it is *approved*, an attribute `ApprovedBy` will  be assigned in the whole *version*.

### Requirement:

There is the requirement of listing the latest **entity versions** of all *entities*, but only the latest approved version of each entity.

### Problem:

I need to find an optimal way of achieveing the whole query for a large-scale solution.

For that reason, I have thought two possible approaches:

1. **IsLast flag column on *EntityVersion***. Whenever a new version is added, the whole transaction will set `true` to the newly added version, and the previously *last version* will be assigned with `false`.
2. **A trigger** that will handle every new *entity version* insertion and will add the new version to a special table which will have the latest versions only. Whenever a new version is added, the previous is dropped from the whole special table. That is, the `SELECT` to obtain the whole listing will be very cheap.

### Question:

What could be the optimal and valid approach? Do you have any other approach in mind?

Thanks!

*Note that "optimal" means that will be scalable and it will work with milions of records*.

---

---

#### Update

*Since I've found that some users in their answers are requesting how is the schema of `Entity`and `EntityVersion`, I'm going to describe them better.*

- ***Entity** has no textual information: just an identifier and relations with other entities.*
- ***EntityVersion** has textual and other information. For example: Title, Description, Author... **It's important to mention that `EntityVersion` does not have any duplicated information from `Entity`.***

*The easiest solution would be having something like a `SELECT DISTINCT` that could both define the distinct column and select other columns in the same query. Sadly, as far as I know, this isn't possible in SQL Server (am I wrong?).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that IsLast flag column is sufficient, but....

1. First question you should answer is: what's the ratio of Entities
   to EntityVersions? This can influence your decision.
2. Also, I'm not sure on your table structure, but I would Assume that EntityVersion table is a copy of Entity table that stores
   changed fields (Or just diffs maybe?). If that's a case, why not
   store the latest version in Entity itself. I think this is a more
   semantically correct approach.
3. Usually, if you have correct indexes (Maybe try to incorporate [columnstoreIndexes](http://rusanu.com/2012/05/29/inside-the-sql-server-2012-columnstore-indexes/)?) you don't have to perform any special work like triggers which can be expensive.  Try to do your tests with regular Join with GroupBy (Or you don't even need a join if your EntityVersion table has all of necessary fields). Or probably this approach is going to be a little faster:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/438990/1792936
4. Again, you can only construct an optimal query based on your execution plan and speed tests.
5. If everything else fails, maybe try to incorporate [CQRS pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) or something similar

Comment: Please check the update in the bottom of my question in order to understand better what `Entity`and `EntityVersion` are. And about your points: 1) It can be great. Think about something like Wikipedia or StackOverflow itself (1 question can have hundred of versions). About the other points, I'm going to take a look, expect some feedback in a day! Thanks for your points.

Comment: In addition, I believe that the 2nd approach could be someting like CQRS pattern. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've read about the column store indexes. It has been a very very interesting reading and it's a very powerful tool. Both CQRS pattern + column store index may be a extremely powerful approach!

Comment: Finally, I'm going to use the approach 2): `Entity` now has a `1:n` relation with `EntityVersion` called `LastApprovedVersionId`. This way, in the object-oriented model, whenever a version for some entity is approved, I set the whole `LastApprovedVersion` association. This is the way! Thanks for your suggestions and as I said in the previous comment, even if I'm not going to use column store this time, it has been a good discovery!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, I hope that works for you. Do not forget, if you still not satisfied with a performance after all query and database optimizations, perhaps hardware upgrade can help you. SSDs can make a significant difference.

Comment: Thanks. It's too early to talk about database optimization. I'm just in the 20% of the development. I was looking to go in the right direction!