# How to eliminate duplicate rows based on column max value in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a view which returns duplicate rows having field performance, which can be 1,2,3 or 4. I need to select only rows which is having max performance. How to do this ? Tried this :

View :

[image]

results needed as follows :

[image]

So basically for each employee number group, I need to fetch what is max calender value and corresponding performance value

Comment: Miising details such as structure of the view and RDBMS that you are using.

Comment: You write that you want the rows with max performance, but your query looks like you want the rows with max "Calender" values.

Comment: It would be nice if you add an example - about a dozen  of rows in a view  and the goal result of a query you try to d esign

Comment: Still you did not told what the sql server is. And what if there would be more than single row having same Employee and same max Calender?

Answer (score 3):

You can express

```
the employee record with the highest performance
```

as:

```
there is no record (for this employee) with a higher performance
```

And that gives:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM employee nx
   WHERE nx.employee_nr = e.employee_number
   AND nx.performance > e.performance
   );
```

Comment: with some RDBMS engines like Firebird/Interbase "NOT EXIST" leads to sub-select for every row. I think this query better reformulated as LEFT JOIN with IS NULL condition. That would be less easy to read, but sometimes considerably faster

Comment: In that case Firebase is an exception. For most DMBSs the performance is the same (even the query plans are the same) or even better than the LEFT JOIN ugliness. The probable reason for this is that EXISTS has existed allmost from the beginneng, while LEFT JOINS were introduced by sql92. (in the old days we had to emulate LEFT JOINS by means of `select ... from a,b WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT FROM a where not exists (SELECT ... FROM b ..);`

Comment: Dunno why. Firebase is really different, for example `insert into TABLENAME select * from TABLENAME` fork bomb :-) I'd expect from small cheap databases like MySQL, Anywhere, SQLite to has less optimizations available as well. I remember I tried to bottom-up calculations of MLM-like tree. `UPDATE table SET (parent re-calculation) where not exists (immediate children that were not calculated themselves)` - looped until "0 rows affected" - in old Interbase 5.5 this ignored all the indices and made a perfect NATURAL x NATURAL :-|

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two queries: read `max calender` for any given `employee group`, then to select the rows with the same those values is calender and group.

```
  Select vm."Employee Number" as eGroup, max(vm.Calender) as Calender From view1 vm
```

That part is obvious. The problem is how to inject it as a criterion for

```
  Select vd."Employee Number", vd.Calender, vd.Performance From view1 vd where ... ?
```

Since aggregate functions (like `max`) gives a singular result, you can use JOIN without risk of having Cartesian sets production (when all combinations of rows from two `select`s are tried, NxM)

```
  Select vd."Employee Number", vd.Calender, vd.Performance From view1 vd 
  Join (Select "Employee Number" as eGroup, max(vm.Calender) as maxCal From view1) as vm
    On (vd."Employee Number" = vm.eGroup) and (vd.Calender = vm.maxCal)
```

Note, this still can produce several rows with the same `Employee Number` and `Calender` if that was how they were in the table. Unless you have a UNIQUE INDEX upon both those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your inputs. I tried a slightly different approach for this.

Step 1 : Since I did not have any unique identifier for each row, I made one by concatenating Employee_Number and Calender columns. 
It becomes easier then and we can use following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      T1.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, T1.Performance, T1.Calender
FROM  dbo.view1 AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.view1 AS T2
       ON T2.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = T1.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
       AND T2.maxval > T1.maxval
WHERE     (T2.maxval IS NULL)
```

Here Maxval is Concatenated column.

Actual answer is here : [SQL Server: Only last entry in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438938/sql-server-only-last-entry-in-group-by/438990#438990)

Answer (score 0):

Your stated goal doesn't match your results, but I would do this (at least in DB2):

```
select e.Employee_Number, e.Calendar, e.Performance
from Employee e
where e.Calendar in (select max(Calendar) from Employee group by Employee_Number)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 select v1.performance,max(v1.field)
 from view1 v1
 group by v1.performance
```

Comment: avoid code only answer, consider adding some text as explanation

Comment: Minus 1.  This doesn't even come close to answering the question.